# Why Flutter test automation is not being running after upgrading to flutter version 3.10.6?

Tags: flutter, ui-automation

After upgrading to flutter version to 3.10.6 and try to run the automation. I noticed that the mobile app was ran on the emulator but the automation is not running it stuck on the first activity of the mobile application.

I am using flutter_gherking: ^2.0.0
The previous flutter version was;
environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"
flutter: 2.10.5

Current:
environment:
sdk: ">=2.18.0"
flutter: 3.10.6

I am expecting to see logs why the automation is not running.